# Exchange 2013 IPless DAG - Change IP address

Tags: exchange-2013

I have 2 Exchange 2013 servers in a IPless DAG

I need to change the IP address on one of the servers. Anyone know if its as simple as ensuring everything running on the other server, change IP, flush DNS and confirm DNS resolution working? Or is there more too it?

I can't find any articles online regarding IPless DAG IP changes

Answer (score 0):

As you use Exchange 2013 IP-less DAG, I think it is similar with Exchange 2016, I found some clues in this article: 
http://www.azure365pro.com/moving-exchange-2016-server-to-another-active-directory-site/

I think you could try the following steps:

1. Place it on Maintenance
2. Change the IP of the Exchange server
3. Restart Exchange Server

In addition, you need to update the related DNS records.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I'm going to give it a crack in a few weeks and will let you know how I go. 

Hopefully everything is just DNS dependent so it works after TTL/cache expires.